# Bitcoin Core wallet and Blockchain.com

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain.info

sorry for the n00b question, it's been awhile since I looked into this. I have a Bitcoin Core wallet on my machine with a backup of the wallet.dat. It's been ages since I opened the application, so I've upgraded it and am re-syncing it.

I also have a Blockhain.com account (originally opened when it was Blockchain.info). I remember that on Blockchain.com I could see my BTC amount. I now can't log into to Blockchain.com because my 2FA device changed and support hasn't gotten back to me for days about how to reset it. Googling suggests their support never gets back.

Since I'm not hearing back from support I'm wondering if I have lost control of my wallet funds. Did the action of creating a Blockchain.com/Blockchain.info account mean I have handed over my wallet to the company and lost this BTC?

Answer (score 1):

> Did the action of creating a Blockchain.com/Blockchain.info account mean I have handed over my wallet to the company

Yes.

> and lost this BTC?

You are wholly dependent on the continuing good-will and competence of the business and its customer support systems and staff.

When Satoshi Nakamoto invented Bitcoin, his famous white-paper said

> What is needed is an electronic payment system based on cryptographic proof instead of trust,
> allowing any two willing parties to transact directly with each other **without the need for a trusted
> third party.**

I feel too many people ignore this.

Comment: lesson learned. re: blockchain.com, do you know if it's possible to get around this issue with the backup phrase?

Comment: @carbonfibre. Yes you probably can. See https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/208771356-How-do-I-make-a-wallet-backup- which links to https://login.blockchain.com/#/recover but you'll need to understand the consequences (it creates a new "wallet" and there's probably other important thing to understand)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily reset the 2FA on your account here
https://login.blockchain.com/#/reset-2fa

Only you have to know what was the original wallet ID and email account.

reset will take 7 days, then you can access the account without 2FA